# defining a global struct pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, global

I need to identify a global struct (array), consisted of 4 integers.
The problem is, size of that struct array is not known in advance.

I'm trying to make sth. like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
    int MAXleft;
    int MAXright;
    int MAX;
} strnum;

int main ()
{
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);

    strnum numbers[size];

    return 0;
}
```

I heard that, it is possible to do this by pointers but I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can allocate the space for several structures dynamically like this:

```
strnum *numbers = malloc( size * sizeof(strnum) );
```

Then you can use it like any regular array (mostly).

It might be more convenient to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. It allocates a number of blocks and fills them with zeros. Please note, that `malloc` doesn't clear allocated memory.

```
strnum *numbers = calloc( size, sizeof(strnum) );
```

When you are done with the memory don't forget to call `free( numbers )`, which will return the allocated memory back to a memory manager.

If you don't `free` it when it's no longer required and allocate some more and more, a memory footprint of the program will grow for no good reason as the program continues to work. This is called a memory leak and should be avoided. It might eventually result in the lack of memory for a program and unpredictable results.

And don't forget to include a `stdlib.h` header with prototypes of memory allocation functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is called [Dynamic Memory Allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

The thing you are trying to do can be done as follows:

```
   strnum* number;
   int size = 0;

   scanf("%d",&size);

   number = malloc(size * sizeof(strnum));
```

Also, don't forget to free the memory once you have done using the array.

```
   free(number);
```

Comment: in C you don't cast what malloc returns, it can issues if you forget to include stdlib.h since by default the return type if there is no prototype is int. By not casting you would catch that.

Comment: I don't think casting of `malloc` makes any difference if you allocate the correct amount of memory.

Comment: If someone writes a program with a cast of result from malloc on a 32-bit PC and try to compile it and launch on a machine with a 64-bit system with 8-byte pointers and 4-byte ints, he or she might have a REALLY hard time trying to understand why the latter doesn't work. The problem is that without a prototype a return value will be truncated to a 4-byte int and will most likely cause a segfault!

Comment: or in other words you get problems if sizeof(int) != sizeof(strnum*) because you don't get a warning since you already told the compiler you know better than it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with malloc() and then do realloc() when the size keeps increasing. 
I would suggest you to allocate a pool of 10 structures at once so that the number of calls to realloc() are reduced.